# What type of cable/connector is this 30 PIN LCD display cable?

Tags: connector, lcd, cables, display, lvds

I need help identifying the type of cable this is. It is used to connect an LCD display panel to a processor board. The width of each connector is about 15 mm and each end attaches to a 30 PIN connector with the word I-PEX on it.

**What is it called so that I can order a few of them?**

[image: Connector]
One end mated to connector.
[image: Cable]
Full cable.
[image: Cable end top]
Cable end top.
[image]
Cable end bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an I-pex Cabline-VSF with lock bar or maybe Cabline-VS. On the VSF page it says "Matable to CABLINE®-VS Receptacle, the VESA standard connector for 16:9 panel application"